# What's wrong with my high & low poly models?

Tags: uv, normals, baking, subdivision-surface, normal-map

[image]

Can anyone check my blender file and my models (high and low).
Why i always getting weird artifacts after baking high on low In Spainter and how can i improve them (topology, UV map etc) ? I cant understand whats the problem ....

P.S / Why its so annoying to do this baking process especially normal maps.. 
Like litteraly every model im trying to bake has some issues in Spainter weird lines, black areas etc ... Can anyone enlighten me what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

People thinks baking normal maps is just a basic step, but really it's not, there is a lot of theory to understand here if your model is even a little bit complex. Just taking a quick look at your files, your low poly isn't a contiguous object, it's made of several parts that aren't linked together, same for your cage. So when the rays sent from your cage towards your low poly reach an intersecting parts the result is artifacts. Your geometry is all wrong, no way this is going to bake properly unless you restart from scratch with proper hard surface modeling techniques (quads, no intersections, support loops...).

On the bright side your UVs looks good! Maybe start with a simple 2 parts model, try to explode it and bake it properly, to help you understand the theory with less possibility for failure. Take it slow and make sure you get it.

But first read this, those 2 posts are basically the Bible of Normal map baking for all 3D softwares and will teach you all you need to know:

http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_Map_Modeling

http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Texture_Baking

Comment: This guy didnt have a contiguous object too (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wK7vd10Uh4k). Just followed the tutorial ... Thx for answer though

Comment: He is baking in Substance Painter which has an option to bake normals based on mesh name or ID color. This is exactly like exploding a mesh for baking. You can have a non contiguous object as your low poly (of course) but you need to explode or do it with a software that support this kind of baking like SP. Hope this help...